# Flex 4.5 - ButtonBar with dynamic image in-between

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5, flex-spark, buttonbar

Is it possible to modify a Spark button-bar (or to use the design/skin(?)) to have a dynamic flash-generated image in between?

```
(button | dynamic image | button)
```

The dynamic image is a double-ended progress bar generated by beginFills and such.

Comment: What is a `double-ended progress bar generated by beginFills and such`? Is it an interactive component? Does it have to be updated by something? Or can it take care of itself?

Comment: the dynamic image is a progress bar that shows the number of results from the button on each side. right now i have it is set inside a spark group in the mxml that calls the buttonbar. i can have the calling mxml feed in data into the buttonbar, if that will help the data flow.

Comment: Any particular reason you absolutely want this in a ButtonBar? Cause it sounds to me like you should just make this a custom component, especially if there will be only the two Buttons? Also a screenshot might make things clearer.

Comment: I like the look of the button bar, so hoped I could recycle it somehow.. Also, the buttonbar is optimized for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

As RIAstar has suggested, why not to use custom component based on, say, s:HGroup?FTQuest